# Can acetaldehyde be condensed with methyl vinyl ketone to form 2-Cyclohexen-1-one as per the Robinson annulation

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, cyclohexane

I have seen that cyclohexanone can react with methyl vinyl ketone to form a fused bicyclic cyclohexenone, I am wondering if the same reaction can be used to produce cyclohexenone the single ring product.

I have since seen that the process can be acid catalyzed in [*Tetrahedron Lett.* **1971,** *12* (52), 4995–4996](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0040-4039(01)97609-9), might there be any obstruction to the formation of the cyclohexenone product?

Comment: There's just too much that can go wrong here. Acetaldehyde is very good at self-condensing when exposed to strong base.

Comment: What if the acetaldehyde was diluted and added drop wise to vinyl ketone slowly.

Comment: Acetaldehyde also polymerises under acid catalysis. I can find no references to a succesful reaction between acetaldehyde and MVK, though I do not have access to Scifinder.